# How I can transfer variable to all clients in Unity with Photon Network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have an enemy object created by InstantiateRoomObject() and this object has an isDead variable with boolean type. The problem is that when player1 kills the enemy, enemy's isDead becomes true and enemy dies but it's going on on player1 client. Other players sees like killed enemy was not killed. Other players don't get enemy's isDead from client1 and on their clients isDead still equals false.
I would like to know how to transfer isDead variable from first client to others.

PS Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

id just not kill it right there and then but send an RPC to all instances through the server then in the script that receives the RPC message kill the monster. that way it is dead on all instances.